# Processing CSV File With R - Finding the Mode

Tags: r, database, algorithm, sorting, csv

I have the following columns in my CSV file, "buildings.csv".

```
Complaint Number    Status  Date Entered    House Number    House Street    BIN Community Board Special District    Complaint Category  Unit    Disposition Date    Disposition Code    Inspection Date DOBRunDate
```

What I would like to do is look at the column, "Complaint Category" and then determine which category comes up the most. They are listed as numbers so for example, I see four rows with number 12 as a category, three rows with number 15 as a category and 20 rows with number 1. I would then have R determine that 1 is the most common complaint type with a total of 20 unique complaints. In other words, how do I find the mode of the "Complaint Category"? Here is my attempted code.

```
buildings <- read.csv("buildings.csv")

Mode <- function(x) {
  +     ux <- unique(x)
  +     ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
  + }



Mode(buildings$ComplaintCategory)
```

Any ideas why it doesn't like the brackets? unexpected '}' in "+ }"

```
Complaint Number    Status  Date Entered    House Number    House Street    BIN Community Board Special District    Complaint Category  Unit    Disposition Date    Disposition Code    Inspection Date DOBRunDate
1347576 CLOSED  4/25/2013   42  WEST 29 STREET                      1015742 105     12  BEST    4/25/2013   H1  4/25/2013   4/26/2013 0:00
3549827 CLOSED  3/8/2016    833 39 STREET                           3330494 312     4M  BEST    3/16/2016   L2  3/16/2016   3/17/2016 0:00
1347611 CLOSED  4/25/2013   42  WEST 29 STREET                      1015742 105     12  BEST    4/25/2013   H1  4/25/2013   4/26/2013 0:00
3546598 CLOSED  2/10/2016   316 KENT AVENUE                         3335795 301     30  BEST    2/23/2016   I2  2/23/2016   2/24/2016 0:00
1347418 CLOSED  4/23/2013   101 WEST 87 STREET                      1032246 107     91  BEST    4/25/2013   L2  4/25/2013   4/26/2013 0:00
4646431 CLOSED  3/9/2016    42-43           27 STREET                           4005110 402     91  BEST    3/16/2016   A8  3/16/2016   3/17/2016 0:00
2182954 CLOSED  3/11/2013   333 WEST 262 STREET                     2817959 208     21  BEST    4/25/2013   L2  4/25/2013   4/26/2013 0:00
4639225 CLOSED  12/10/2015  32-49           37 STREET                           4010329 401     86  BEST    1/6/2016    H3  1/5/2016    1/7/2016 0:00
1346947 CLOSED  4/16/2013   21  EAST 1 STREET                       1088698 103     21  BEST    4/26/2013   L2  4/25/2013   4/27/2013 0:00
1418990 ACTIVE  3/16/2016   222 EAST 14 STREET                      1006900 103     21  BEST                3/17/2016 0:00
4542654 CLOSED  3/6/2013    86-52           PINTO STREET                        4224111 408     21  BEST    4/26/2013   L2  4/25/2013   4/27/2013 0:00
3540897 ACTIVE  12/16/2015  7819    BAY PARKWAY                         3162372 311     91  BEST    12/16/2015  D4  12/16/2015  12/17/2015 0:00
4545284 CLOSED  4/9/2013    45-18           SMART STREET                        4445273 407     21  BEST    4/29/2013   L2  4/27/2013   4/30/2013 0:00
3546801 CLOSED  2/11/2016   161 DUPONT STREET                       3063780 301     3   BEST    2/23/2016   I2  2/23/2016   2/24/2016 0:00
3443838 CLOSED  5/8/2013    461 39 STREET                           3010445 307     2E  BEST    5/8/2013    P6  5/8/2013    5/9/2013 0:00
4638942 CLOSED  12/7/2015   97-38           64 AVENUE                           4050468 406     86  BEST    1/6/2016    I2  1/6/2016    1/7/2016 0:00
3443837 CLOSED  5/8/2013    461 39 STREET                           3010445 307     2E  BEST    5/8/2013    P6  5/8/2013    5/9/2013 0:00
3550169 ACTIVE  3/10/2016   766 METROPOLITAN AVENUE                 3068892 301     30  BEST    3/10/2016   D4  3/10/2016   3/11/2016 0:00
4545931 CLOSED  4/17/2013   142-02          BOOTH MEMORIAL AVENUE               4140189 407     83  BEST    5/21/2013   L2  5/21/2013   5/22/2013 0:00
4637834 CLOSED  11/24/2015  61-20           BLEECKER STREET                     4084597 405     4K  BEST    11/24/2015  A3  11/24/2015  11/25/2015 0:00
3447488 CLOSED  6/14/2013   2123    E 5 STREET                          3191975 315     2E  BEST    6/14/2013   P6  6/14/2013   6/15/2013 0:00
4646432 ACTIVE  3/9/2016    42-50           27 STREET                           4541854 402     91  BEST    3/10/2016   D4  3/10/2016   3/11/2016 0:00
1349193 CLOSED  5/21/2013   222 EAST 104 STREET                     1088784 111     21  BEST    5/21/2013   L1  5/21/2013   5/22/2013 0:00
```

Could someone please direct me the best way to approach this? Thanks

Comment: I added more information.

Comment: try the tapply command:  tapply(fishPassage$"Complaint Category", INDEX=fishPassage$"Complaint Category", FUN =length).  This will provide the count for all of the Complaint Categories.  In the future please use dput to load your data.

Comment: Just use sort(table(fishPassage[['complaint Category]]))[1]

Comment: Added my updated attempt to the code. Why doesn't it like the brackets?

Comment: @42- do we need decreasing=TRUE in your sort function? - otherwise it returns the lowest frequency item. Note also that the mode is not necessarily unique. May also be necessary to return all values with frequency equal to the highest.

Comment: @dww Good catch. I sent that from my iPhone while drinking a beer so didn't have the chance to test it. Should be Just use `sort( table(fishPassage[['ComplaintCategory']]), decreasing=TRUE)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same using this way:

```
buildings <- read.csv("buildings.csv")

Mode <- function(x) {
     tbl <- table(x)
     ans <- tbl[which.max(tbl)]
     return (ans)
}

Mode(buildings$ComplaintCategory)
```